# How to catch an exception of "using mypackage"?

Tags: julia

Is it possible to `try using` a package?

```
try
    using A
catch e
    showerror(STDOUT, e)
end

unsupported or misplaced expression using
```

I am expecting to see error message like

```
using A
LoadError: ArgumentError: A not found in path
```

Comment: `using` is only allowed at the top level scope. A workaround can be to use `eval(:(using A))` instead of `using A` and then the `try` works as expected. The difference comes from `eval` which evaluates expression in the top level scope.

Comment: @user3580870 It works well thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`using` is only allowed at the top level scope. A workaround can be to use `eval(:(using A))` instead of `using A` and then the `try`-`catch` works as expected.

The difference comes from using `eval` which evaluates its expression argument in the top level scope.

```
julia> try
           eval(:(using A))
       catch e
           showerror(STDOUT, e)
       end
ArgumentError: A not found in path
```